# Facing issue after download file in xls format in php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

i want to export data in excell sheet from mysql database. below is my code. The code is working fine and data is exporting in excell sheet with given file name.

```
<?php
$filename = "ALL_Report_$date_time";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "SELECT * from test_db";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or 
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . 
mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select 
database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . 
mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
 }
 print("\n");    
 //end of printing column names  
 //start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
 }

 ?>
```

but the main probel is when i am trying to open the file one warning is pop up. If i click on Yes then the file is opening. below is the Warning.

```
The file format and extension of 'file_name.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe.Unless you trust its source don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?
```

Can anyone help please how can i avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0):

For a proper export must Use PHPexcel https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel is well documented.

Here is an example:

```html
// Create your database query
$query = "SELECT * FROM myDataTable";  

// Execute the database query
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Instantiate a new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
// Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
// Initialise the Excel row number
$rowCount = 1; 
// Iterate through each result from the SQL query in turn
// We fetch each database result row into $row in turn
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    // Set cell An to the "name" column from the database (assuming you have a column called name)
    //    where n is the Excel row number (ie cell A1 in the first row)
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['name']); 
    // Set cell Bn to the "age" column from the database (assuming you have a column called age)
    //    where n is the Excel row number (ie cell A1 in the first row)
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['age']); 
    // Increment the Excel row counter
    $rowCount++; 
} 

// Instantiate a Writer to create an OfficeOpenXML Excel .xlsx file
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
// Write the Excel file to filename some_excel_file.xlsx in the current directory
$objWriter->save('some_excel_file.xlsx');
```